# append various inputs to display it as a string

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I have the following problem, I want to display two text inputs as a list element but I do not know how to append various variables. The code below only shows the first input in the list.

```
function addLi () {
 
    let x = document.createElement("LI");
    let name= document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("name").value);
    let city= document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("city").value);
   x.appendChild(name) 
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(x);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You create `let city` but never use it. As for creating `<input>` you don't create any but state that's what you want to create. What are expected html results?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way (just an example with a loop):

```js
document.getElementById('add-btn').addEventListener('click', addLi);

function addLi() {
  const items = ['name', 'city'];

  for (let item of items) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const value = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById(item).value);
    li.appendChild(value);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="name" value="John Doe"> <input id="city" value="Sydney">
<button id="add-btn">Add to list</button>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```